# Setup suspend-on-lid-close/Fn+F4 outside of KDE/Gnome?

Tags: 10.04, laptop, suspend, acpi

On current Ubuntu (10.04) suspend-on-lid/<kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> only works if some powermanagement-applet of KDE/gnome is running.

But what about suspend-to-lid if you are working on the console or using a non-bloated window-manager?

What is the current mechanism to configure suspend-on-lid system wide?

What of hald/udev/acpid/foo-kit/random-thing is the right place to hook this feature in?

What is the up-to-date command to suspend from the command line/script?

```
echo -n mem > /sys/power/state
pm-suspend
pmi
```

or something else?

Btw, if it matters, I want to configure it on some Thinkpads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ryan Thompson [described](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349/how-come-power-manager-settings-does-not-work-when-computer-is-under-virtual-cons/1868#1868) how the system works in an answer to my question earlier.

So, you just need to change `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` to do whatever you want instead of blanking the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, finally I have configured the suspend-on-lid-close action everywhere via acpid.

For minimal changes to existing system wide config files (i.e. less manual overhead for the next upgrade), I did it like this:

```
cd /etc/acpi
mkdir local
echo -e "#!/bin/sh\npm-suspend" > local/lid.sh.post
chmod u+x local/lid.sh.post
```

It is then automatically called by /etc/acpi/lid.sh (if no gnome/kde power-manager running). I used pm-suspend, because it is already used in /etc/acpi/sleep.sh.

Now I have to figure out how to enable Fn+F4 system wide ...

**Edit:** Well, it seems that Fn+F4 -> sleep (everywhere) should work out-of-the-box under Ubuntu, because the thinkpad-acpi module is loaded by default (when booting a thinkpad) and the default

```
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/hotkey_mask
```

masks the Fn+F4 event, s.t. an ACPI event should be generated. A default acpid should then call /etc/acpi/sleep.sh (which calls pm-suspend).

First tests of Fn+F4 did not work (i.e. did not trigger acpi events) - but some strange side-effect (e.g.

```
cat /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/hotkey_mask
```

, toggling the thinklight via

```
echo on > /proc/acpi/ibm/light
```

or something like this) made it work now ...

Comment: Your answer is considerably better than mine, you should've accepted it instead.

Answer (score 1):

I run the AwesomeWM on Lucid from my X201 Thinkpad. I just run the gnome-power-manager applet in my WM instance by having it setup in my autostart script for Awesome. It does eat up a little ram (30M res) but works well with the normal hibernate/suspend modes. The nice thing is it also gives me my battery indicator and such as well.

I know it's not just the script commands, but my understanding is that there more than just a script to run. It starts up and monitors some events, dbus, etc.